# which file to back up in Cpanel account?

Tags: backup, cpanel

Please I had some issues with the party hosting my website, when i contacted another party they requested me to transfer my site to a folder "backup" in the root of my account so that they can see if they can deploy it or not. Which files should I put in this folder they said? please I need an answer it is very ugrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login your cPanel and create new backup of your account so that you will get your all files with the latest content to your new host.

You can generate backup with the following steps.

Login your cPanel >> Backup >> Download a full website backup >> and click on "Generate Backup"

Above steps will create the backup file in your root directory account. Then you will have to provide them your login details so that they will migrate your site.